# Django admin interface reading __str__() after inline delete

Tags: python, django, django-admin

**Context:**

I'm just starting out with Django. To get familiar with it, I'm writing a web app to track bills in a household. Each bill has associated bill portions for each person that owes money. The amount owed is calculated by the bill's total amount divided by the total number of portions (i.e. the number of people involved). See below:

```
class Bill(models.Model):
  description = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  amount = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=2)
  paid_by = models.ForeignKey(Person)

  def __str__(self):
    return self.description

class BillPortion(models.Model):
  bill = models.ForeignKey(Bill, related_name='portions')
  person = models.ForeignKey(Person, related_name='bill_portions')

  @property
  def amount(self):
    return self.bill.amount / self.bill.portions.count()

  def __str__(self):
    return str(self.person) + ' owes ' + str(self.bill.paid_by) + \
           ' $' + str(self.amount) + ' for ' + str(self.bill)
```

**Issue:**

My application's admin interface has Bills that also include related BillPortion objects inline using `admin.StackedInline`. When I delete the last BillPortion connected to a particular bill, I get a DivisonByZero error in the BillPortion's `amount()` property. The property is being read by the BillPortion's `__str__()` method.

It appears that after the BillPortion object is removed from the database, it is then trying to read the portion's `__str__` method. But because it no longer exists in the database, the `str(self.amount)` causes the DivisionByZero error.

Why would the admin interface be trying to read the `__str__()` method of an object I've just removed? Should I edge-case the `amount()` method?

Comment: You need an if condition in your helper method named amount. That is where you do the division when count is zero.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why would the admin interface be trying to read the **str**() method of an object I've just removed? Should I edge-case the amount() method?

My quess would be because it uses that property to display information (messages package).

you could try overriding the `__str__` and then doing a check that self.amount exists/returns correctly, if not, return an empty string or some other readable message.

Comment: I think this is the most elegant way. I ended up catching the exception in the BillPortion's `__str__`. Thanks!